# C: variable has initializer but incomplete type

Tags: c, struct

Trying to get my head around the old C language. Currently on structs and getting this error:

```
"variable 'item1' has initializer but incomplete type"
```

Here's my code:

```
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    float rate;
    int quantity;
} item;

void structsTest(void);

int main()
{
    structsTest();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void structsTest(void)
{
    struct item item1 = { 1, "Item 1", 345.99, 3 };
    struct item item2 = { 2, "Item 2", 35.99, 12 };
    struct item item3 = { 3, "Item 3", 5.99, 7 };

    float total = (item1.quantity * item1.rate) + (item2.quantity * item2.rate) + (item3.quantity * item3.rate);
    printf("%f", total);
}
```

I guessed perhaps the struct defintion was in the wrong location so I moved it to the top of the file and recompiled, but I am still getting the same error. Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Get rid of `struct` before `item`, you've typedef'd it.

Answer (score 10):

`typedef struct { ... } item` creates an unnamed `struct` type, then `typedef`s it to the name `item`. So there is no `struct item` - just `item` and an unnamed `struct` type.

Either use `struct item { ... }`, or change all your `struct item item1 = { ... }`s to `item item1 = { ... }`. Which one you do depends on your preference.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that

```
typedef struct { /* ... */ } item;
```

does not declare the type name `struct item`, only `item`. If you want to be able to use both names use

```
typedef struct item { /* ... */ } item;
```