# Error: variable ‘v1’ has initializer but incomplete type

Tags: c

I am creating a simple program in C to manipulate points by using structs. So far I've looked into these two answers:

- [Error: variable ‘database’ has initializer but incomplete type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142394/error-variable-database-has-initializer-but-incomplete-type)
- [C: variable has initializer but incomplete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515287/c-variable-has-initializer-but-incomplete-type)

The second of which looks strikingly similar to my situation. However, when I try to replicate the format of the question I unfortunately keep getting the same problem as I am not using a `struct` in my main function and imported the `typedef` from my header file. Here is my code:

**function.c**

```
#include "function.h"
struct _vector{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
 };
```

**function.h**

```
 struct _vector;
 typedef struct _vector vector;
```

**main.c**

```
#include "function.h"
int main(){
 
     vector v1 = {0.1,0.2,0.3};
     vector v2 = {0.3,0.4,0.5};
 
     vector v3 = crossprod(v1,v2);
 
     return 0;
 
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: The `struct _vector` definition should be in `function.h`, not `function.c`.

Comment: The way you've organized it is only appropriate for opaque types (e.g. `FILE`), not if the user of the type is allowed to access the members.

Comment: Each C file is compiled as its own unit. When main.c complies, `function.h` says that `vector` is a `struct _vector`, but it doesn't say anything about its members. As a result, the initializer list, `{0.1,0.2,0.3}` doesn't make sense at that point in time.

Comment: With what @Barmar suggested I have changed the very definition of ```struct _vector``` to **function.h** and removed it from **function.c** this solved all compilation errors. This problem is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout is wrong, try

**function.h**

```
struct _vector{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};
typedef struct _vector vector;
```

**main.c**

```
#include "function.h"
int main(){

    vector v1 = {0.1,0.2,0.3};
    vector v2 = {0.3,0.4,0.5};

    vector v3 = crossprod(v1,v2);

    return 0;
}
```

function.c will not be included automatically.

Comment: Why are you defining _vector with nothing and then declaring it as a typedef? Remove the first `struct _vector` and put the typedef after the second one.

Comment: @Tordek Ah sorry about that, I had copy pasted so it slipped my mind.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'll go ahead and fix that, I didn't know there was a specific way you had to write header files lol.

Comment: @PQCraft: You **can** include definitions of functions and objects in header files, but you **should not**. As far as a C compiler is concerned, they are just part of the source code. But when we make software projects, more than just a simple source file or two, we use a model in which header files “tell” other files what their associated source file defines. All the object and function **definitions** related to some concept `foo` should be in a file `foo.c`, and its non-definition **declarations** should be in `foo.h`. Then other files include `foo.h` to learn about the declarations.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do `vector v1 = {0.1,0.2,0.3};`, the compiler needs to know the complete definition of `vector`. Since you haven't provided this, the compiler has no way to know what bytes `{0.1,0.2,0.3}` should result in.

---

**Option 1: Provide a complete definition of the structure**

`function.h`:

```c
typedef struct Vector {
   double x;
   double y;
   double z;
} Vector;

Vector Vector_crossprod(Vector v1, Vector v2);
```

`function.c`:

```c
#include "function.h"

Vector Vector_crossprod(Vector v1, Vector v2) {
   Vector v;

   // ...

   return v;
}
```

`main.c`:

```c
#include "function.h"

int main(void) {
   Vector v1 = { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 };
   Vector v2 = { 0.3, 0.4, 0.5 };
 
   Vector v3 = Vector_crossprod(v1, v2);
 
   return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- Added missing `void` in `int main()`.
- No need for the underscore. Structure names have their own namespace.
- I use uppercase for type names (to permit `Vector vector`).
- Added "class" name to function as a namespace. This isn't very important for `crossprod`, but you'll see why it becomes important in the next option.

---

**Option 2: Keep using an opaque type**

If you want to continue hiding the definition of the structure, you'll need to use pointers and provide a constructor.

`function.h`:

```c
typedef struct Vector Vector;

// Returns NULL and sets errno on error.
Vector *Vector_new(double x, double y, double z);

void Vector_free(Vector *v);

// Returns NULL and sets errno on error.
Vector *Vector_crossprod(Vector *v1, Vector *v2);
```

`function.c`:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "function.h"

struct Vector {
   double x;
   double y;
   double z;
};

Vector *Vector_new(double x, double y, double z) {
   Vector *v = malloc(sizeof Vector);
   if (!v)
      return NULL;

   v->x = x;
   v->y = y;
   v->z = z;

   return v;
}

void Vector_free(Vector *v) {
   free(v);
}

Vector *Vector_crossprod(Vector *v1, Vector *v2);
   Vector *v = malloc(sizeof Vector);
   if (!v)
      return NULL;

   // ...

   return v;
}
```

`main.c`:

```c
#include "function.h"

int main(void) {
   int rv = 1;

   Vector *v1 = Vector_new(0.1, 0.2, 0.3);
   if (!v1) {
      perror("Can't allocate vector");
      goto ERROR1;
   }

   Vector *v2 = Vector_new(0.3, 0.4, 0.5);
   if (!v2) {
      perror("Can't allocate vector");
      goto ERROR2;
   }
 
   Vector *v3 = Vector_crossprod(v1, v2);
   if (!v3) {
      perror("Can't determine vector crossproduct");
      goto ERROR3;
   }
 
   rv = 0;

   Vector_free(v3);
ERROR3:
   Vector_free(v2);
ERROR2:
   Vector_free(v1);
ERROR1:
   return rv;
}
```